Spring boot TCP Socket Server using Spring Integration
I have a TCP Socket Server using spring integration.
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.dsl.Tcp;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.dsl.TcpServerConnectionFactorySpec;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractServerConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpConnection;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayLfSerializer;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.ErrorMessage;


@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class TcpServerConfig
{

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TcpServerConfig.class);
  public static final String IP_HEADER = "ip_connection";

  public TcpServerConfig()
  {}

  @Bean
  public AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverFactory()
  {
    TcpServerConnectionFactorySpec factory = Tcp.netServer(4444)
      .serializer(new ByteArrayLfSerializer())
      .deserializer(new ByteArrayLfSerializer());
    return factory.get();
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel inboundChannel()
  {
    return new DirectChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow()
  {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(serverFactory()))
      .channel(inboundChannel())
      .get();
  }

  @Bean
  public Executor executor()
  {
    return Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
  }

  @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inboundChannel")
  public MessageHandler inboundHandler(TcpSocketServer aTcpSocketServerHandler)
  {
    return message -> {
      try
      {
        byte[] payload = (byte[]) message.getPayload();
        String data = new String(payload);

        MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();
        headers.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + value));

        TcpConnection connection = headers.get("ip_connectionId", TcpConnection.class);

        logger.info("Received message: {}", data);
        aTcpSocketServerHandler.handleMessage(data, connection);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        logger.error("Error processing message", e);
        throw e;
      }
    };
  }

  @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
  public MessageHandler errorHandler()
  {
    return message -> {
      ErrorMessage errorMessage = (ErrorMessage) message;
      logger.error("Error occurred: ", errorMessage.getPayload());
    };
  }
}

and im using the following tcp socket client for testing purposes

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String hostname = "localhost";
    int port = 4444;
    String message = "Hello, TCP Server!";

    try (Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port))
    {

      // Send message to the server
      OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
      output.write((message + "\n").getBytes());
      output.flush();

      // Read response from the server
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
      String response;
      while ((response = reader.readLine()) != null)
      {
        System.out.println("Server response: " + response);
      }

    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
      System.err.println("I/O error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
  }

When i try the MessageHeaders i get the following results:

ip_connectionId: 127.0.0.1:53129:4444:e9aad42f-a057-4c02-87fc-0cc9a60427fe
ip_localInetAddress: /127.0.0.1
ip_address: 127.0.0.1
id: 1ad8f0c5-a882-83d6-8f55-ceddce8961bf
ip_hostname: 127.0.0.1
timestamp: 1718618786314

As you can see the ip_connectionId header is a string, so I cant get the TcpConnection object from it.
I need the TcpConnection object so i can inject it in the TcpSocketServer handler so I can send messages back to the client.
I have been searching for solutions but i cant find anything that can work.
I know that we can get the client Socket connection by using plain Java and java.net.Socket but by using the spring integration solution i cant find a way to get the TcpConnection object.
Is this even possible using this solution of spring integration?
Thank you.
